# undefined local variable or method `createaddress_hotel_users_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have:

```
<%addr.each_with_index do |addr,index|%>

<%if addr==''%>

<%= index+1%>

<%= form_tag createaddress_hotel_users_path, method: :get do %>

<div style="display:none">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
</div>

<textarea cols="67" id="address<%= index+1%>" name="hotelUser[address<%= index+1%>]" rows="3">
</textarea>

<p style="text-align: center;width: 50%;">

<a href="#" id="example-hide" class="btn-orange3" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">BACK</a>

<%= submit_tag("PROCEED TO PAYMENT")%>
```

In routes:

`resources :hotel_users`

In controller i have an action as `createaddress`. I want to submit the form to this action `HotelUsersController`.But i am getting the above error. Add also i need `textarea` value in the url after submitting the form, so that i can get params value.

Comment: what is in your routes?

Comment: please see the above code i have edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not set up a route for it

```
resources :hotel_users do
  get 'createaddress', on: :collection
end
```

Comment: thanks it works, but how do i get textarea param value since it is dynamic